# Expand a matrix with polynomials

Tags: matlab, matrix, polynomial-math

Say I have a matrix A with 3 columns `c1`, `c2` and `c3`.

```
1 2 9
3 0 7
3 1 4
```

And I want a new matrix of dimension (3x3n) in which the first column is `c1`, the second column is `c1^2`, the n column is `c1^n`, the n+1 column is `c2`, the n+2 column is `c2^2` and so on. Is there a quickly way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining [PERMUTE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), and [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), you can do this quite easily such that it works for any size of `A`. I have separated the instructions for clarity, you can combine them into one line if you want.

```
n = 2;
A = [1 2 9; 3 0 7; 3 1 4];
[r,c] = size(A);

%# reshape A into a r-by-1-by-c array
A = permute(A,[1 3 2]);

%# create a r-by-n-by-c array with the powers
A = bsxfun(@power,A,1:n);

%# reshape such that we get a r-by-n*c array
A = reshape(A,r,[])

A =

     1     1     2     4     9    81
     3     9     0     0     7    49
     3     9     1     1     4    16
```

Comment: I was just working on a general `bsxfun` solution when you posted this :-) I'll leave my answer as it stands as this is more elegant than what I'd come up with. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (don't have access to Matlab right now), it should work

```
    A = [1 2 9; 3 0 7; 3 1 4];
    B = [];
    for i=1:n
         B = [B  A.^i];
    end
    B = [B(:,1:3:end)  B(:,2:3:end)  B(:,3:3:end)];
```

More memory efficient routine:

```
    A = [1 2 9; 3 0 7; 3 1 4];
    B = zeros(3,3*n);
    for i=1:n
         B(3*(i-1)+1:3*(i-1)+3,:) = A.^i;
    end
    B = [B(:,1:3:end)  B(:,2:3:end)  B(:,3:3:end)];
```

Comment: `B` is growing inside the loop, which is very inefficient for large `n`.

Comment: Inefficiency can be avoided by defining B = zeros(3,3*n) and by changing the line inside the loop to B(3*(i-1)+1:3*(i-1)+3,:) = A.^i;

Comment: Agreed. But depending on level of experience, the OP may not realize this, so it would be best if you made it explicit in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
n = 4;
A = [1 2 9; 3 0 7; 3 1 4];
Soln = [repmat(A(:, 1), 1, n).^(repmat(1:n, 3, 1)), ...
        repmat(A(:, 2), 1, n).^(repmat(1:n, 3, 1)), ...
        repmat(A(:, 3), 1, n).^(repmat(1:n, 3, 1))];
```